# Как получить якорь URL web-приложения в CherryPy?

Tags: python, url, cherrypy

Возник вопрос по поводу CherryPy: допустим, имеется web-приложение, разработанное на нем, и потребовалось каким-либо образом получить доступ к якорю URL, если он есть.
Условно, вот простейший пример кода, который выведет URL с параметрами, но без якоря:

```
import cherrypy

class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return cherrypy.url(qs=cherrypy.request.query_string)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   cherrypy.quickstart(Root(), '/')
```

Соответственно, если после запуска открываю URL, например, http://localhost:8080?param=123#fragment, то на экран выводится http://localhost:8080?param=123, но не #fragment.
Возможно ли как-то получить фрагмент URL, который после #? Может ли кто-то, пожалуйста, помочь?